# Display related products on category view

Tags: ajax

Currently have a fancybox loading when "add to basket" is selected from a category page. The fancybox displays required custom options, like colour etc, so you dont have to visit the product page to add it to basket.

I'd like to display related products within that fancybox also, any ideas?

I currently have a ajaxoptions.phtml with container2 added etc and a ajax.xml, but no idea how to get related into that fancybox.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a product id in your facybox popup you can get related product much easily

```
 $object = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
 //Get product detail using product id  (Suppose you have product id is : $product_id)
   $_product = $object->load($product_id);
 $Relate_product = $_product->getRelatedProductCollection();
```

From this array of data you can show your related product collection